# How can i convert a text into an array of useful data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am extracting text from a server. The data I'm extracting is not organized for further use. The text I'm extracting looks like this:-

```
>>[Extracted] id: 194805284, got 55 points from  jones  (252906152669) date: 15/04/19 08:44:40 you have 30 points remaining
```

I don't want all this text I only want the id, points, number, and date.

Note: I might extract more than one of the message once in a while.

So to extract the id, points, number, and date, I wrapped every word with a span tag and then used this code:

```
var getData = {
    //gets the id, points, date and number respectively
    number1 : $('span:contains("id:")').next().text(),
    amount : $('span:contains("got")').next().text(),
    time : $('span:contains("date:")').next().text(),
    number : $('span:contains("date:")').prev().text()
}
```

The reason I'm using this code is that I might extract automatically more than 1 message, so with every message that gets extracted, every word that it contains is the same except the id, points, date, and number.

I used the above code to extract the data I want, but this time there was 2 [extracted] messages, look below.

HTML

```
<p>[Extracted] id: 194805284, got 55 points from  jones  (252906152669)
 date: 15/04/19 08:44:40 you have 30 points remanining  [Extracted] id: 193537533, got 3 points from  Micheal (907794804)
 date: 14/04/19 10:15:32, you have  100 points remaining</p>
<div class="processed-data">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
// wrap every word with <span> tag
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("p").append($("<span>").text(v));
});

//extract the id, points, time and number respectively
var getData = {
    number1: $('span:contains("id:")').next().text(),
    amount: $('span:contains("got")').next().text(),
    //amount : $('span:contains("got")').next().text().substring(1),
    time: $('span:contains("date:")').next().text(),
    number: $('span:contains("date:")').prev().text()
}

// Output the extracted data to .processed-data div
$('.processed-data').append("thisTime = { [id: " + getData.number1 + " amount: " + getData.amount + ", time: " + getData.time + " number: " + getData.number + "]}'");
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Buubiye/u6b9qm70/21/)

output:

```
thisTime = {[id: 194805284,193537533, amount: 553, time: 15/04/1914/04/19 number: (252906152669) (907794804) ]}'
```

The results I expect are: 
For each [extracted] message to get its own array. By using a loop or anything else.

Example:

Now I'm getting this;

```
thisTime = {
        [id: 194805284,193537533, // All the ids are stored in 1 array data 
        amount: 553, // All the points are stored in 1 array data e.t.c
        time: 15/04/1914/04/19 
        number: (252906152669) (907794804)]
        }
```

I want to get:

```
thisTime = {
[id: 194805284, 
amount: 55, 
time: 15/04/19
number: (252906152669)],
[id:193537533, 
amount: 3, 
time: 14/04/19 
number: (907794804)]
}
```

I only want each message I extract to have its own array.

Comment: your "wanted" result has incorrect syntax.

Comment: Alex Kudryashev i have changed the syntax.

Comment: still incorrect. :(

Comment: before splitting every word by space in the Paragraph tag... do a split on [Extracted] so it will give you each extracted message as an item in array... then you treat each extraction as P to split by space and so on.

Comment: Nawed Khan i tried doing so, but when i split them by paragraph i failed multiple times. I couldn't put the output on different arrays using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Regex to solve it, I think is better than Jquery method that you are using.

See a possible Regex solution:

```js
var text = '[Extracted] id: 194805284, got 55 points from  jones  (252906152669)  date: 15/04/19 08:44:40 you have 30 points remanining  [Extracted] id: 193537533, got 3 points from  Micheal (907794804)  date: 14/04/19 10:15:32, you have  100 points remaining';
var textArray = text.split('[Extracted]');

var regularExpression = /id:\s+([0-9]+).+got\s+([0-9]+).+[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)\)\s+date:\s+([0-9\/\s:]+)/i;
var output = [];
var item;
for(var i = 1; i < textArray.length;  i++){
 item = textArray[i].match(regularExpression);
 output.push({
  id: item[1].trim(),
  amount: item[2].trim(),
  time: item[4].trim(),
  number: item[3].trim()
 });
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is a better solution than mine. Because i can easily deploy it on the server side.

Comment: Vinicius i wanted the item[3] to be the number which is wrapped with brackets (252906152669)  not the name jones. So can you tell me how i can get that number?

Comment: @Axmednuur I updated the answer, please check if is ok now!

Comment: thanks for the great answer. But can you please tell me why item[].trim() is not working on node.js server?

Comment: @Axmednuur sory for the late. I created a Express.js app here and the example code worked ok for me. Could you give me more details about your problem?

Comment: thanks for the help, I have solved this issue long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a regular expression (Regex) to solve this -- is there any particular reason you're wrapping each word in a span?

The following regular expression should match all tokens in your string:

`id:\s+(\d+),\s+got\s+(\d+)\s+points\s+from\s+.+?\s+\((\d+)\)\s+date:\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)`

I'm using `\s+` here instead of spaces because it seems the spacing in your above template is inconsistent, and just to be safe I like to use `\s+` for any whitespace of any quantity.

You can extract a message like so...

```
const regex = /id:\s+(\d+),\s+got\s+(\d+)\s+points\s+from\s+.+?\s+\((\d+)\)\s+date:\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/; // construct the regex literal
const message = // some string matching your "extracted" template

const match = message.match(regex); // now your match contains all the data

const [fullMatch, idString, pointString, dayString, monthString, yearString, hourString, minuteString, secondString] = match; // you don't have to destructure, but this is the order of the capturing groups.
```

You should also be able to match multiple as well, by doing the following...

```
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(message)) {
  // now match can be handled the same way as above. You could alternatively push the matches to a list as well here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is **getData**. I suggest to decompose the string splitting on **Extracted** and after on spaces. After, you can select sub spans grouping by sentences and filter in order to create an array containing one or more objects.

```js
var sentences = $("p").text().split("\[Extracted\]").slice(1);
$("p").empty();
$.each(sentences, function(i, v) {
    var words = ['Extracted'].concat(v.trim().split(/ +/));
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
        $("p").append($("<span/>", {text: word.trim()}));
    });
});

var result  = {thisTime: $("p span:contains(Extracted)").map(function(idx, txt) {
    var x = $(this).nextUntil('span:contains(Extracted)');
    return {id: x.filter('span:contains("id:")').next().text(),
        amount: x.filter('span:contains("got")').next().text(),
        time: x.filter('span:contains("date:")').next().text(),
        number: x.filter('span:contains("date:")').prev().text()};
}).get()};
$('.processed-data').append(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>[Extracted] id: 194805284, got 55 points from  jones  (252906152669)
    date: 15/04/19 08:44:40 you have 30 points remanining  [Extracted] id: 193537533, got 3 points from  Micheal (907794804)
    date: 14/04/19 10:15:32, you have  100 points remaining</p>
<div class="processed-data">
</div>
```